# Latest and second latest column values

Tags: mysql

I want to find the latest and second latest column values difference on group type. And the type count must greater than 1.

Consider this sample data in my table:

```
type  value        date
--------------------------------
 2       5   2015-05-09 12:42:00
 4     -42   2015-05-09 13:19:57
 2       2   2015-05-09 14:48:30
 2       7   2015-05-09 12:54:39
 3      16   2015-05-09 13:19:57
 3      20   2015-05-09 15:01:09
```

I would like the result to be

```
type   Value   
---------------------
  2     -5
  3      4
```

i.e, For the type 2, the latest value is 2, and the second latest value is 7, so difference between them is -5.

Comment: Please add the query you tried/found out yourself.

Comment: The date should be unique within the group, otherwise this is not a deterministic task....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use variables to reduce the number of table scans needed:

```
SELECT   type, 
         value
FROM (  SELECT   @n := IF(type = @t,  @n+1, 1) as num,
                 @t := type                    as type,
                 @v - value                    as value,
                 @v := value
        FROM     mytable
        ORDER BY type, 
                 date DESC) base
WHERE   num = 2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/821e08/19)

The idea is to give records a record number that for each different value of *type* starts from 1 again and then increases with descending date values.

Three variables are kept updated while going through the records in order of type and descending order of date:

- *@n*: the record number given to the previous record;
- *@t*: the value of the *type* column in the previous record;
- *@v*: the value of the *value* column in the previous records;

All three are updated as follows:

If for the current record the *type* value is the same as in the previous record, then *@n* increases with one, otherwise it is reset to 1.

For each record also the difference between the *value* of the current and previous record is returned.

*type* and *value* are updated to reflect the current record's values.

Finally, only records with number two are kept in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select t1.type, t1.value - t2.value as value
from mytable t1
join mytable t2 using(type)
where t1.date = (
    select max(date) 
    from mytable t1m 
    where t1m.type = t1.type
  )
  and t2.date = (
    select max(date)
    from mytable t2m
    where t2m.type = t1.type
      and t2m.date <> t1.date
  )
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a3298/2